# Retornar n últimos registro de um arquivo JSON em php

Tags: php, json

Dúvida PHP com JSON: Já sei como dar loop num arquivo JSON e mostrar todos registros e também mostrar apenas o último registro usando o END. Tem como eu mostrar os últimos 5, 10 registro, por exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Para usar uma parcela de um array, basta usar [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-splice.php).

---

```
$input = array( "vermelho" , "verde" , "azul" , "amarelo" , "preto" , "cinza" );
array_splice( $input , 0 , -5 );
print_r( $input );
```

<sub>**output**</sub>

```
Array
(
    [0] => verde
    [1] => azul
    [2] => amarelo
    [3] => preto
    [4] => cinza
)
```

Comment: Não é retornar parte de um array. Isso sei. É retornar uma quantidade N de registro de um arquivo JSON, e não todos registros. Entendeu?

Comment: Isso. No exemplo retornei apenas os *5* últimos.

Answer (score 0):

Não é isso que preciso. Tenho um arquivo JSON e já sei dar um loop e retornar todos registros. 
Se eu precisar apenas de último registro uso o END assim:

```
    $pesquisa = json_decode(file_get_contents("nomedoarquivo"),true);
    $ultimoRegistroPesq = end($pesquisa["registros"]);
    $strCampo = $ultimoRegistroPesq['campo'];
```

Quero saber se tem como limitar a pesquisa aos 5 últimos registros, por exemplo. Se fosse pesquisa a um banco de dados eu usaria LIMIT 5 na query. Mas com JSON não sei.

Comment: Não precisa criar uma resposta, edite sua pergunta se for necessário acrescentar alguma informação sobre a questão.